# migrating-data-from-corda-2-to-corda-3 without data loss

Tags: corda

I am referring the link

[Migrating data from Corda 2 to Corda 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301744/migrating-data-from-corda-2-to-corda-3)

Can anyone please let me know

1) Rerun the transactions means , manually rerun all the previous transactions or is there any way to rerun it automatically?

2) If it is manual re run, how do we make sure the order of the transactions ?

3) In case if there is any date constraint written in the code, rerun will fail. Isn't?

We have Customer RFP and want to share a migration plan , without losing any data.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By re-run, I meant:

1. Emptying the nodes' databases
2. In the order in which they were originally performed, perform each transaction from scratch again

   - e.g. by invoking the flows to run these transactions

Unfortunately:

- There is no built-in way to perform this process automatically
- Yes, certain time-window constraints will fail. You may have to write the contract accordingly (e.g. either there is a timewindow or the transaction happened before time X)